# get the selected value position

Tags: android, arrays, android-alertdialog, android-spinner

I am using a button to display a popup.Its like a spinner but as i was not getting a popup as spinner i used a button.All the values of the popup i am getting from the string array.Now what i want to do is that if user selects "Male" from the popup i want to send the code associated with it to the web service not "Male" it self.

Gender Array

```
<string-array name="Gender">
        <item>Select Gender</item>
        <item>Male</item>
        <item>Female</item>
    </string-array>
```

Gender Id array

```
<string-array name="Gender_id">
        <item>Select</item>
        <item>2</item>
        <item>1</item>
```

Popup

```
 public static void showDialog(Context c, String title, final String[] array, final Button b) {
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(c);
        builder.setTitle(title);
        builder.setItems(array, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                b.setText(array[i]);
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        });

        builder.show();


    }
```

Now suppose if user selects "Female" from the popup,2 should be send to the server,so basically i want the position of what users selects so that i can give to other array and get the code

Comment: just create a class variable like selectedGender and in onclick event assign value to it. like selectedGender = i; and use this variable as a value you want to sent to the web service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve you problem.**

**main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSelectGender"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Select Gender"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**MyActivity.java**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private Button btnSelectGender;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        btnSelectGender = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSelectGender);
        btnSelectGender.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(MyActivity.this, "Select Gender", getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Gender),new onGenderSelected() {
                    @Override
                    public void genderSelection(int position) {
                        btnSelectGender.setText(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Gender)[position]);
                        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this,getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Gender)[position]+" >>> "+getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Gender_id)[position],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        System.out.print("Gender Title : " +getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Gender)[position]);
                        System.out.print("Gender Value : " +getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Gender_id)[position]);
                    }
                });
            }
        });


    }

    public static void showDialog(Context c, String title, final String[] array,final onGenderSelected target) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(c);
        builder.setTitle(title);
        builder.setItems(array, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                target.genderSelection(i);
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        });

        builder.show();


    }
    public interface onGenderSelected{
        public void genderSelection(int position);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Spinner item  create like this

```
 Spinner display_spinner = (Spinner)  findViewById(R.id.datadisplay_spinner);

 ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> record_length_spinner_adapter = ArrayAdapter
            .createFromResource(youractivity.this, R.array.Gender, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
 record_length_spinner_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
 display_spinner.setAdapter(record_length_spinner_adapter);
```

Comment: i havent used a spinner, i have used a button